# Setting label text from array, why isn't this working?

Tags: xcode, arrays, object, uilabel

I have the following code which isn't working, can someone tell me why?

If I put label1.text = @"XX" into the loop this populates so it is obviously something to do with adding these objects into the array. Can I do this?

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:label0.text,label1.text,label2.text,label3.text,label4.text,nil];
   for(int i=0; i<labelStrings.count;i++) {
       labels[i] = @"XX";
    }
```

Comment: replace labelStrings.count to labels.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `initWithObjects` you fetch, let's say, `label0.text`. That is just a string value, the value of the label's text at this moment. It is not a magic pointer for setting the label's text or anything like that.

Then when you set `labels[i]` you merely replace one string in the mutable array with a different string.

The way to do what you want to do is make an array of the *labels* and then, for each item of the array set its `text` property.

Something like this (typed directly, not tried, so watch out, this code might have errors in it):

```
NSArray *labels = @[label0, label1, label2, label3, label4];
for(int i=0; i<labels.count; i++) {
   [(UILabel*)(labels[i]) setText: @"XX"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes sense. I tried initially to create the array filled with label1, label2 etc but then in my loop when I try and call labels[i].text = @"XX" I get a compile error "property text not found on type (id)" What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Look at the difference between your code and mine! I'm showing you how you must do it. You can't use the `.text` property in this situation.

Comment: Oh sorry, for some reason I didn't notice the code part of your answer! Thanks, huge help :) One day I'll know what I am doing ;p

Comment: You didn't notice the code part because I hadn't written it yet. :)

Comment: By the way, did you know that you are allowed to make an IBOutletCollection? It *is* an NSArray. So if these are labels in your interface, you could have an IBOutletCollection pointing to *all* of them, and then you wouldn't have to form the NSArray in code.

Comment: No I didn't know that. My labels are in my interface so I will give that a whirl, thanks!